# SAPUI5 - Scatter chart with two plots

Tags: sapui5

I want to plot a scatter chart with timestamp values in x-axis. 'Power' and 'No of plugs' in y-axis. The Power values is in the range of 0 - 60000 and 'No of plugs' in the range of 0 - 600. When I tried with the below code I'm getting wrong plot.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>


        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Power Measurements</title>

         <script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.viz,sap.ui.layout">
         </script>


        <script>


      var inputData = $powerValues;
      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
        graphData : inputData
      });

      var dataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({ 
            dimensions : [
             {
               axis : 1,
               name : 'Timestamp',
               value : "{timestamp}"
             }
            ],

            measures : [
                        {
                        group: 1,
                            name : 'Power  (in KW.h)',
                            value : '{power}'
                        },
                        {
                        group: 2,
                            name : 'No of Plugs',
                            value : '{plugs}'
                        }
            ],

            data : {
              path : "/graphData"
            }

          });


        var line = new sap.viz.ui5.Scatter({
                id : "idscatter",
                width : "100%",
                height : "400px",
                title : {
                  visible : true,
                  text : 'Power Utilisation'
                },
                xAxis : {
                  title : {
                    visible : true
                  }
                },
                yAxis : {
                  title : {
                    visible : true
                  }
                },
                dataset : dataset
              });


      line.setModel(oModel);
      line.placeAt("content");

       </script>
      </head>
      <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

[Click here for existing output chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjVTa.png)

In the above chart I need timestamp as x-axis. 'No. of plugs' and 'Power' as two different plots in the same chart (Values of these two are in different ranges).

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a JSFiddle?

Comment: If you are using the latest version of SAPUI5, you should consider using the `sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame` for charting.